# What does "red hot" mean?

Tags: meaning

For instance, a vendor who is crying in the street "red hot! red hot!".
Does it mean a chili pepper? The action takes place in New Orleans.

Comment: Unless you're reading this in a book, you should just walk up to them and ask.

Comment: Is the vendor saying "red hot," or "red hots?" The latter is more likely...

Answer (score 6):

A "red-hot" is any of several varieties of mild sausages known also as "hot dogs" or "frankfurters".  See [the Wikipedia disambiguation page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_hot) for more information, and see [here](http://www.dragonstrider.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/461-Red-hots!-Get-Your-Red-Hots!.html) for a personal memoir (including the disappointment that what are sold as "red hots" were often ordinary hot dogs, and not their reddish and spicier [cousins](http://carolinapackers.com/about-bright-leaf-hotdogs/red-hots/)).

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: @Motti -- appropriate citation added.

Comment: And if the link rots?

Comment: Look on my Works, @Mari-LouA, and [despair](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/learning/poem/175903).